# Cannot Remove Contacts

Tags: 13.04, delete, contacts

When I add a new contact phone number, email, etc in the Contacts app. And I want to remove contacts name, It can't deleted and there is not appeared shortcut menu and remove option by right-click. So, I can't delete any Contacts. How to solve the problem and how to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the contacts list:

- Click the contact you wish to remove
- Right-click the name on the right-hand side (where you would usually left-click to edit the name)
- A delete option will appear, click that and the contact will be removed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I think remove the contact from the left side and right-click before by read the documentation.